# Find a particular folder and find files recursively

Tags: command-line, powershell, windows-server-2008

`Get-ChildItem \\host1\dir\ -recurse -Filter *.txt`
this command searches all the text files recursively in the `dir` folder ,  i want to start the search from `dir1` for instance which is a child folder of `dir` and i am unable to make this work `Get-ChildItem \\host1\dir1\ -recurse -Filter *.txt`  the error was the file does not exist, the dir1 folder is present inside `d` directory .How can i directly find a file in the `dir1` folder.
file hierarchy

> dir
>
> > --d
> >
> > > --dir1

Answer (score 1):

You can't enumerate a drive starting from a none existing path.

Change

```
Get-ChildItem \\host1\dir1\ -recurse -Filter *.txt
```

to

```
Get-ChildItem \\host1\dir\d\dir1\ -recurse -Filter *.txt
```

Comment: but i don't want to add the path to the folder ,but i can generalize a pattern  to search where the folder can be , is there any powershell command to get the path of any folder.

Comment: something like this `(gci c:\ -Directory -Recurse -Filter "dir1").FullName`?

Comment: If `dir1`is unique under `c:\dir` use `gci (gci c:\dir -Directory -Recurse -Filter "dir1").FullName -File -Recurse -Filter *.txt`